# Returning array from Keycloak's script mapper

Tags: serialization, wildfly, claims-based-identity, keycloak

I've like to write [`ScriptBasedOIDCProtocolMapper`](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/protocol/oidc/mappers/ScriptBasedOIDCProtocolMapper.java) script to handle some custom logic for my role claim. Unfortunately I'm unable to return properly serialized array.

i.e. when script returns following array:

```
["one", "two"]
```

claim value is serialized as a map:

```
...other claims...   
claimName: { 0: "one", 1: "two" }
```

where I'd expect JSON array:

```
...other claims...   
claimName: ["one", "two"]
```

What can I do about that?

I'd like to avoid providing custom protocol mappers, I've got other use cases for script mappers, i.e. handling `scope` and `aud` claims.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've intensified my searches and I've just found an answer to the question

> How do I create a Java array from JavaScript?

on Rhino [FAQ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/FAQ#How_do_I_create_a_Java_array_from_JavaScript.3F)

> You must use Java reflection. For instance, to create an array of java.lang.String of length five, do
>
> `var stringArray = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(java.lang.String, 5)`;
>
> Then if you wish to assign the string "hi" to the first element, simply execute
>
> `stringArray[0] = "hi"`;

However to make it work I needed to modify it a little by adding `.class` to get expected type definition:

```
java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(java.lang.String.class, 5);`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the `Java.to` method, e.g.

```
var roles = ["one", "two"]
export Java.to(roles, "java.lang.String[]")
```

This is the fastest way I found.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).